# Error parsing XML: mismatched tag XOSP

Tags: java, android, c++

I'm trying compile android rom but I'm getting error when building.
Error and xml file lines are below:

ERROR THAT I'M GETTING:

```
device/sony/shinano-common/overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/cr_config.xml:18: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag

build/core/package_internal.mk:389: recipe for target '/home/yanun/XOSP/out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/package-export.apk' failed
make: *** [/home/yanun/XOSP/out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/package-export.apk] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file '/home/yanun/XOSP/out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/package-export.apk'
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

#### make failed to build some targets (04:23 (mm:ss)) ####
```

All Lines of `cr_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">

   <!-- Whether cpu boost is enabled for application's 1st launch. -->
    <bool name="config_enableCpuBoostForAppLaunch">true</bool>
  <!-- <integer name="launchboost_timeout_param">2000</integer> -->
   <!-- <integer-array name="launchboost_param_value"> -->
        <item>0x40804000</item> <!-- CPUBOOST_MAX_FREQ Core resource opcode-->
        <item>0xFFF</item>     <!-- CPUBOOST MAX_FREQ resource value-->
        <item>0x40800000</item> <!-- CPUBOOST_MIN_FREQ Core resource opcode-->
        <item>0xFFF</item>     <!-- CPUBOOST MIN_FREQ resource value-->
        <item>0x41800000</item> <!-- CPUBW_MIN_FREQ resource opcode-->
        <item>140</item>       <!-- CPUBW_MIN_FREQ resource value-->
        <item>0x40400000</item> <!-- POWER COLLAPSE resource opcode-->
        <item>0x1</item>        <!-- POWER COLLAPSE resource value-->
        <item>0x42C10000</item> <!-- STORAGE CLK SCALING resource opcode-->
        <item>0x1</item>        <!-- STORAGE CLK SCALING resource value-->
   </integer-array>- 18 LINE
  <!-- <bool name="config_enableCpuBoostForOverScrollerFling">true</bool> -->
  <!-- <integer-array name="flingboost_param_value"> -->
        <item>0x41800000</item> <!-- CPUBW_MIN_FREQ resource opcode-->
        <item>0x33</item>       <!-- CPUBW_MIN_FREQ resource value-->
        <item>0x40800000</item> <!-- CPUBOOST_MIN_FREQ CORE resource opcode -->
        <item>0x4B0</item> <!-- CPUBOOST MIN_FREQ resource value -->
        <item>0x40C28000</item> <!-- SCHEDGROUP resource opcode-->
        <item>0x1</item>        <!-- SCHEDGROUP resource value-->
   </integer-array>

< <!-- <bool name="config_enableCpuBoostForScroller">true</bool> -->
  <!-- <integer-array name="scrollboost_param_value"> -->
        <item>0x40800000</item> <!-- CPUBOOST_MIN_FREQ CORE resource opcode -->
        <item>0x506</item> <!-- CPUBOOST MIN_FREQ resource value -->
   </integer-array>


    <!-- Extended Boosts for QPerformance -->

    <!-- Boost parameters which get passed to QPerformance -->
  <!-- <integer-array name="onbootboost_param_value"> -->
       <item>0x40804100</item> <!-- CPUBOOST_MAX_FREQ Core resource opcode-->
       <item>0xFFF</item>      <!-- CPUBOOST MAX_FREQ resource value-->
       <item>0x40800100</item> <!-- CPUBOOST_MIN_FREQ Core resource opcode -->
       <item>0x6A4</item>      <!-- CPUBOOST MIN_FREQ resource value -->
    </integer-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an opening tag in comments:

```
 <!-- <integer-array name="launchboost_param_value"> -->
```

but in line 18 you have a closing tag uncommented

```
</integer-array>
```

Either uncomment the first starting tag to match the ending, or put into comments the `</integer-array>` like:

```
<!-- </integer-array> -->
```

Looking at your `xml` I suppose you need to uncomment the starting tag.

**Note:** You  have the same mistake 2 times more at exactly the same tag  at line 20, 27 and 30, 33 and 39, 44.

Also one more mistake in line 29, the symbol `<` at start of the line.

Comment: So I need to edit/delete some tags in line 20,27,30,30,39 and 44?

Comment: I think you need to un-comment the starting tags as stated in my answer above.

Comment: New errors when deleted comments from lines. https://pastebin.com/nYg2c8Ek

Comment: You are still having starting tags in comments and ending tag not in comments. Plus you cannot comment a parent tag and leave uncommented its child tags. So either put in comments **ALL** the lines from the starting tag to the ending tag, or un-comment them all.